# How do you SSH over a VPN client on Mac OS X?

Tags: ssh, vpn

Never really had to do this, but I'm using the CISCO VPN client and I'm just trying to figure out how to ssh over it...  Been googling, but this is totally foreign to me.  Was hoping someone here could give me a link to a good beginner tutorial or tell me how to do it using terminal (if that's even what you do...)?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be a DNS issue? Maybe your lookup is

(a) not finding abc.example.com or
(b) finding abc.example.com through an external (WAN) interface, instead of the VPN

If you have an internal (192.168...) ip address for this machine, try that instead of the hostname.

Comment: If that was the answer, then mark it as the answer so that others know your question has been answered and so that grossvogel gets credit for answering it.

Answer (score 2):

As a replacement for Cisco's VPN client, you could VPN over SSH yourself.

On mac there is a great little utility that wraps ssh terminal. It will show you the ssh terminal equivalent. Its called SSH Tunnel Manager and you can download it here. 
http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/stm/

Here's an example of the command line it will generate for you
ssh -N -p 22 -C -c 3des user@ssh.mycompany.com -L 3389/internalhost1.mycompany.com/3389 -L 2022/internalhost2.mycompany.com/22 -L 8080/internalhost3.mycompany.com/80

This will forward local ports 3389, 22, and 3128 to three different hosts via the ssh server of your company. Now to ssh into host2, you would run ssh username@localhost -p 2022 which will forward to internalhost2.mycompany.com:22

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal window:

ssh user@hostname

Comment: that just keeps timing out...  I'm connected to abc.example.com via the VPN client, and I'm using ssh me@abc.example.com in terminal. Should it be something else?

Comment: @Chris, Can you please explain how "ssh user@hostname" is going to ssh over Cisco VPN ?

Answer (score 1):

As Chris says : just do it.

When a VPN connection is made it looks that your PC is directly connected to the company network and all machines become available to you (well, within the limits set by the sysadmins) transparently.

The VPN creates a secure tunnel over the internet to the router at the company and presents itself as a virtual network interface which allows packets to be transmitted/received directly to/from the company LAN.